# Kibana: Visualize based on substring of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We are logging messages from backend systems and then we are using Kibana so we can review the logs there. The only thing I can modify through the code is the 'message' field of the logged document, which contains the actual log entry. Now I want to make a Visualization in Kibana (installed version: 5.6.3) that makes a graph based on a certain sub-string of this message - in my case execution time.

So for example we have a message in format: "Execution time: 123ms", I filter that with lucene like `message: "Execution time*"` and then I want to make a graph showing average execution time per second. I read about the painless script and tried playing with some aggregation buckets giving them this json to match the number:

```
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc.message = /(\\d)/.matcher(doc.message).replaceAll('$1')"
    }
}
```

But I couldn't get it working by far. How can I make the Y axis to be the average of the integers in the message and the X axis the time Date Histogram?